# Selecting from left-joined query in MYSQL in nodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am trying to create a json object with the following information

Tables

1. movies: primary key MovieID
2. actors: primary key ActorID
3. acted in: intermediate table for M to N reltionship for movies and actors
            primary key = MovieID and ActorID.

Here is What I am trying to do.

1. Select actor where ActorID=1

Query :

```
SELECT * FROM actors WHERE ActorID=1.
```

2. Select all movies that the actor acted in.

Query :

```
SELECT * 
  from movies 
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
    ( SELECT *
       from actedin 
  WHERE ActorID = '+actorID+'
  ) AS actors_temp 
    ON movies.MovieID=actors_temp.MovieID AS movies_actor
```

3. find average of column RTRating.

Query : 'SELECT AVG(RTRating) From movies_actor';

4. find average of column MTRating.

Query : 'SELECT AVG(MCRating) From movies_actor';

Here is my nodeJS code.

Assume app = express(), con = connection to mysql.
I am appending the results of queries to actors variable and sending them back via res.send.

```
//#4 ActorID-> actor data, movies data, average rating 
app.get('/actor',function(req,res){
    let query_actorID = con.escape(req.query.actorID);
    let selectActor = 'SELECT * from actors WHERE ActorID = '+query_actorID;
        con.query(selectActor, function(err,result){
        if(err) throw err;
    console.log('retrieved actor info');
    console.log(result);
    var actor = result[0];
    var actorID = con.escape(actor.ActorID);
    //Retrieve Actor information
    let movie_query = 'SELECT * from movies LEFT JOIN (SELECT * from actedin WHERE ActorID = '+actorID+') AS actors_temp ON movies.MovieID=actors_temp.MovieID AS movies_actor'; 
    con.query(movie_query, function(err,movies){
    if(err) throw err;
        console.log('retrieved movies info');
        console.log(movies);
        actor.movies = movies;
        let RTR_query = 'SELECT AVG(RTRating) From movies_actor';
        con.query(RTR_query, function(err,average){
        if(err) throw err;
            console.log('retrieved movies info');
            console.log(average);
            actor.averageRTRating = average;
            });
        let MCR_query = 'SELECT AVG(MCRating) From movies_actor';
        con.query(RTR_query, function(err,average){
        if(err) throw err;
            console.log('retrieved movies info');
            console.log(average);
            actor.average_MCRating = average;
            });
        });

    res.send(JSON.stringify(actor));
    });
});
```

My syntax is apparently wrong. I think I am using AS incorrectly.

Comment: movies_actor does not exist. I tried to make a temporary table from the first query in my example but I did not know how to save that selected table to be used in the second query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested it but it should work.
Movie_query has been simplified. You have to consider that data returned by RTR_query and MCR_query is an array. I've done a single query, it will be more effective.
In your code, you have actually used RTR_query in place of MCR_query.
I hope it will help.

```
//#4 ActorID-> actor data, movies data, average rating 
app.get('/actor',function(req,res){
    let query_actorID = con.escape(req.query.actorID);
    let selectActor = 'SELECT * from actors WHERE ActorID = '+query_actorID;
    con.query(selectActor, function(err,result){
        if(err) throw err;

        console.log('retrieved actor info');
        console.log(result);
        if (result.length == 1) {
            let actor = result[0];
            let actorID = con.escape(actor.ActorID);
            //Retrieve Actor information
            let movie_query = 'SELECT * from actedin INNER JOIN movies ON (movies.MovieID = actedin.MovieID) WHERE actedin.ActorID = ' + actorID; 
            con.query(movie_query, function(err,movies){
                if(err) throw err;

                console.log('retrieved movies info');
                console.log(movies);
                actor.movies = movies;

                let MCR_RTR_query = 'SELECT AVG(RTRating) AS rtrating_avg, AVG(MCRating) AS mcrating_avg From movies_actor';
                con.query(MCR_RTR_query, function(err,averages){
                    if(err) throw err;

                    console.log('retrieved movies info');
                    console.log(average);
                    actor.averageRTRating = averages[0].rtrating_avg;
                    actor.average_MCRating = averages[0].mcrating_avg;
                });
            });

            res.send(JSON.stringify(actor));
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.title 
  FROM actors a
  JOIN movie_actor ma
    ON ma.actor_id = a.actor_id
  JOIN movies m
    ON m.movie_id = ma.movie_id
 WHERE a.name = 'Denzel'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for help!!